# VBS- Can I exit a VBS message box that repeats itself without going to the task manager or cmd?

Tags: vbscript, taskkill

I have a message box that repeats itself whenever you click ok- which is the only option, by the way.

My code:

```
    'Very Annoying script'   
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

intMessage = Msgbox("Click ok to say yes",16, "Is this messagebox annoying?")

If intMessage = vbOK Then
    RETRY
Else
Wscript.Quit
End If
SUB RETRY
'Very Annoying script'   
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

intMessage = Msgbox("Click ok to say yes",16, "Is this messagebox annoying?")

If intMessage = vbOK Then
    RETRY
Else
Wscript.Quit
End If
End sub
```

Can I end the following script without ending the process labeled Micorosft Windows based Script Host'?
That includes not running the cmd line (It won't work)

```
    taskkill /im wscript.exe
```

**OR**

going to the task manager.

Comment: It's really annoying to have to go into task manager and delete every single process.

Comment: Also, I don't understand you fully. What do you mean by 'why tell us what you want in real, as a user'

Comment: sorry, why NOT tell us what you want in real, as a user

Comment: What I want is a faster and simpler way to end the script then going to task manager, because I want to run the script and not be caught using Task Manager in school. The teachers think it's dangerous, which is complete nonsense. Also, Maybe a script that can simply end the task (taskkill won't work)

Comment: taskkill /f /im should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this command `taskkill /IM wscript.exe /F` ; You kill all the running vbscript, but
If you have a lot of a running script in loop with differents paths, you can use this vbscript to choose which one to be killed or not .So the aim of this script is to select and focus to the process that you want to be killed and you can also save it in a log file.
Just give a try ;)

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count,strComputer
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "Il y a une instance déjà en cours" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"Il y a une instance déjà en cours"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
Copyright = "[© Hackoo © 2015 ]"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
NomFichierLog="Killed Process.txt"
temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
strComputer = "."
    Call Find("wscript.exe")
    Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
End If
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Processus "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" en cours d'exécution "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    Count = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        'Processus = Mid(objItem.CommandLine,InStr(objItem.CommandLine,""" """) + 2) 'Extraction du chemin du script en ligne de commande
        Processus = objItem.CommandLine 'Replace(Processus,chr(34),"")
        Question = MsgBox ("Voulez-vous arrêter ce script : " & DblQuote(Processus) & " ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'Tuer ce processus
            OutPut.WriteLine Processus
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'décrementer le compteur de -1
        End if
    Next
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & "ont été arrêtés"
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*") & VbCrLF 
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: That's really cool. Thank you. Do you know an internet source where I can learn more vbs?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do end the script is to use

```
    taskkill /f /im wscript.exe
```

Other then that, it will simply re-run the script (the same effect as when you just simply click ok)

Thank you to Jiang YD for answering